# Datagridview tries to shows column header when editing

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have datagridview with more records which beyond the windows form height. So I use form/datagrid vertical scroll bar to view bottom rows.

I use form scroll bar instead grid scroll bar to view bottom rows (grid column headers hide) and click the grid cell then the datagridview automatically moves towards upside and tries to show column header when grid is in editable mode.

I need the datagrid should keep in same position even when the column headers hided into form.

Before cell click(Scroll down the form then datagridview column header hide):

[image]

After cell click column header display automatically:

[image]

Comment: Hi and Welcome on Stackoverflow. Is this WebForms or WinForms? Would you mind adding a screenshot?

Comment: My need is keeps the datagridview position same even the column headers hided by screen.

Comment: Hi Marcel this is windows form